# Intercept call while in conversation

Tags: android

I have an app where I intercept the incoming calls (with the CallLogObserver) and save that in the db.

But when I am in call and anyone call me, obviously the system doesn't intercept the call, because the call goes to the sms center.

I don't want to use "Call Waiting".

It's that possible?